# File upload progress bar won't 'move' unless clicked

Tags: angular, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar, bootstrap-modal

I have a situation using `Angular2 version 4` where a file upload progress bar is shown in a dialog box. The issue is unless I click on the dialog-box, the progress bar does not 'move', meaning it won't 'progress'.

The dialog box is shown using [ng2-bs3-modal](https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal):

```
import { ModalComponent } from "ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal";
@Component({
   selector: "my-selector",
   templateUrl: "app/my/my.html"
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('myModal')
  fileUploadModal: ModalComponent;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.progressEvent = this.progressService.progressEvent$.subscribe(event => {
      this.progress = event.percentCompleted;
      this.speed = event.uploadSpeed;
      this.timeRemaining = event.uploadTimeRemaining;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();

      console.log(this.progress, this.speed, this.timeRemaining);
   });
  }
  open(): void {
    this.fileUploadModal.open();
  }
}
```

Template Markup:

```
<modal #myModal>
<modal-header [show-close]="true">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Upload File</h4>
</modal-header>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #modalForm="ngForm">
<modal-body>      
    <input type="file" #fileInput (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" name="myfile" class="form-control" />
</modal-body>
<modal-footer>
    <div class="progress" style="float: left; width: 60%">
      <!--<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [attr.aria-valuenow]="progress" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [style.width]="(progress/100)*100 + '%'"></div>-->
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': progress + '%' }"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="myModal.dismiss()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!modalForm.valid">Save</button>
    </div>
</modal-footer>
</form>
```

This is how I bind:

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [attr.aria-valuenow]="progress" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [style.width]="(progress/100)*100 + '%'"></div>
```

Also tried:

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': progress + '%' }"></div>
```

I can see in the console that `progress`, `speed` and `timeRemaining` variables are being updated correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: how did you show the `dialog-box`?

Comment: @Pengyy I have updated the question. Essentially it is a wrapper around bootstrap 3.